# Why are the switch-case part and runtime polymorphism is not working?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I've got a problem with (switch-case) part and I've tried to test some run-time polymorphism in main. It is not working. And in switch case ; it always says:

> Your choice is not available.

And at the end it does not quit the program. It continuous with a loop.
How should I do to get rid of this problem?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tempName;
        int tempQueue;
        double tempKilo, tempCalibre;
        String tempAgri;
        ArrayList<Farmer> farmers = new ArrayList<>();
        final int capacity = 2;

        for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++)            {
            System.out.println(" Please enter the farmer's name : ");
            tempName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" Please enter the queue number : ");
            tempQueue = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(" Please enter the calibre of the cherry : ");
            tempCalibre = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(" Please enter the kilo of the cherry : ");
            tempKilo = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
            Cherry cherry1 = new Cherry(tempName, tempQueue, tempCalibre, tempKilo);
            farmers.add(cherry1);
            cherry1.displayMenu();
            cherry1.Price();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Please enter the farmer's name : ");
            tempName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" Please enter the queue number : ");
            tempQueue = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println(" Please enter the production type of Apple : ");
            tempAgri = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(" Please enter the kilo of the apple : ");
            tempKilo = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
            Apple apple1 = new Apple(tempName, tempQueue, tempAgri, tempKilo);
            farmers.add(apple1);
            apple1.displayMenu();
            apple1.Price();
        }
        ArrayList<Farmer>farmers1=new ArrayList<>();
        int checkpoint;
        boolean isPFruitAvailable;
        double totalPrice;
        while(true) {
            display();
            checkpoint=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            switch(checkpoint) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(" Please enter the name of the farmer that you want... ");
                    tempName=sc.nextLine();
                    isPFruitAvailable=false;
                    for(Farmer fruit : farmers1) {
                        if(fruit.getName().equals(tempName)) {
                            farmers1.add(fruit);
                            System.out.println("Your choice is successfully added.");
                            isPFruitAvailable=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!isPFruitAvailable) {
                            System.out.println(" Your choice is not available");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    totalPrice=0.0;
                    System.out.println(" Please enter the name in the cart . ");
                    System.out.println(" Checking out...");
                    for(Farmer fruit1 : farmers1) {
                        fruit1.displayMenu();
                        totalPrice+=fruit1.Price();
                    }
                    System.out.println(" Price is "+totalPrice);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(" Thanks for your informations...");
                    System.out.println(" The program quits within a second... ");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void display() {
       System.out.println(" Welcome to fruit transfer system... ");
       System.out.println(" Press 1 to add fruit into the system... ");
       System.out.println(" Press 2 to check fruit you want... ");
       System.out.println(" Press any key to quit the program.... ");
    }
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned u r getting the o/p `Your choice is not available.` it means the name of the  farmer doesn't match any of the farmer names in the list

Comment: I 've already created an ArrayList to refer the farmer's names. If I type the name which is match but it again says the same response. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never populated your farmers1 list, it is always empty therefore isFruitAvailable is always false. Also, your while loop never terminates, it just keeps spinning ("break" statements that you have are inside switch and have nothing to do with "while")

```
for(Farmer fruit : farmers1) {
    if(fruit.getName().equals(tempName)) {
        farmers1.add(fruit); //the only place where you add something, but it never gets executed
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop is probably supposed to run over `farmers` instead of `farmers1` (the latter could get a more meaningful variable name as well, maybe `basket` or `shoppingCart`).

Comment: @Thilo yes, indeed

Comment: Yep, you're right. I've debug the problem. Now it is the to deal with other problems :D

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to compare the new farmer with the list of farmers alredy populated i.e. `farmers` and if it matches any add it to `farmers1` list.

Therefore inside the `switch` case change the `for` loop as shown below:

```
// Compare the farmer tempName with the list of farmers already populated
for(Farmer fruit : farmers) {
    if(fruit.getName().equals(tempName)) {
        farmers1.add(fruit);
        System.out.println("Your choice is successfully added.");
        isPFruitAvailable=true;
        break;
    }
}
```